Run a long-running process on Windows using SSH
As part of my pipeline, I need to launch Selenium server on a windows machine (which is a long-running process) and let the pipeline keep running. So I need to run a SSH command that will run the selenium server, but will not hang. I have SSH Server installed on the windows machine.
I've tried these methods, with no success:

ssh myuser@windows_host "powershell -Command \"Start-Process 'java' '-jar selenium-server-standalone.jar' -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput 'C:\\path\\to\\logfile.log' -RedirectStandardError 'C:\\path\\to\\logfile.log'""
ssh myuser@windows_host "start /B cmd /C 'java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar > C:\\path\\to\\logfile.log 2>&1'"

in both cases, my shell from where I run the SSH command returns, with no output. Also, the log files contains no content..
Any idea?

Check the selenium server log files : https://vbvtrp.medium.com/extracting-logs-from-a-selenium-session-5d1bb7b07a45
